# scaling data to specific range in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization

I would like to scale an array of size [192,4000] to a specific range. I would like each row (1:192) to be rescaled to a specific range e.g. (-840,840). I run a very simple code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing as sp
sample_mat = np.random.randint(-840,840, size=(192, 4000))
scaler = sp.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-840,840))
scaler = scaler.fit(sample_mat)
scaled_mat= scaler.transform(sample_mat)
```

This messes up my matrix range, even when max and min of my original matrix is exactly the same. I can't figure out what is wrong, any idea?

Comment: Please [reprex] with input data and expected output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this manually.
It is a linear transformation of the minmax normalized data.

```
interval_min = -840
interval_max = 840
scaled_mat = (sample_mat - np.min(sample_mat) / (np.max(sample_mat) - np.min(sample_mat)) * (interval_max - interval_min) + interval_min
```

Comment: Yes this works too but I am wondering how come minmaxscaler messes the range up?

Comment: For me, minmaxscaler with feature_range provides the correct method. 
If however your problem is that not every row is scaled to your interval, that is simply how minmaxscaler works. It normalizes your entire matrix, leaving the scales within the matrix the same. 
If you want to normalize each row individually, you have to fit a scaler for every row, or run the normalization for every row individually.

Answer (score 0):

MinMaxScaler support `feature_range` argument on initialization that can produce the output in a certain range.
`scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(1, 2))` will yield output in the `(1,2)` range